# facebook didCompleteWithResult

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

im using facebook login in my app and a want to proceed user to main interface after he logged oon facebook.

Here is how im handling results:

```
- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"FB login failed");
    }
    else if (result.isCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"FB login cancelled");
    }
    else {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"fbLogin" sender:self];
        NSLog(@"User logged in");
    }
}
```

The problem is that in good case my `NSLog(@"User logged in");` calls, but segue doesnt perform

[image: segue]

Added:
Here is my viewDidLoad method to provide login button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    fbLoginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile"];
    fbLoginButton.publishPermissions = @[@"publish_actions"];
    fbLoginButton.delegate = self;
}
```

And AppDelegate.m :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
                             didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
    [FBSDKLoginButton class];
    [FBSDKShareButton class];
    return YES;
}
```

I also want to say, that login works correctly, its just segue problem

Comment: can you show some additional code of FB login

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik updated

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31880464/unable-to-get-the-email-id-of-the-user-when-log-in-with-facebook-sdk-in-ios

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik any other ideas?

Comment: where you called this in `- (void)loginButton:(FBSDKLoginButton *)loginButton didCompleteWithResult:(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *)result error:(NSError *)error  in the VIEW Controller or didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33513630/how-to-get-email-id-of-user-using-facebook-sdk-4-7-in-ios-9/33513692#33513692